# Headless with specific profile in Chrome/Chromium

Tags: java, google-chrome, selenium, ubuntu, headless

I have problem with headless with Chrome/Chromium, because I can't use specific profile of Chrome or Chromium in headless mode. In firefox with geckodriver I didn't have that problem, but I resignate because geckodriver use to much ram. In google-chrome/Chromium Headless mode is use Default profile, but when I try check where is xpath with command chrome://version, there's only in tmp folder, so every time when I open my project with headless it will be new random profile but I have to use in my project specific cookies and save pages. How can I use specific profile or use Default profile but not in tmp folder ? I was looking on every topic on this site and I still didn't find answer for this problem. I'm using Ubuntu 18.04 and Java Selenium.